# Listview in fragment crashes the app

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to implete listview into fragment.But my app is crashing here is my fragment code

```
public class ConversationFragment extends Fragment {
    public View rootView=null;
    private ListView lv;
    private ArrayList<String> strArr;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String name = getArguments().getString("name");
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation, container, false);
        TextView username=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        username.setText(name);
        strArr=new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,strArr);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.get_from_user).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.get_from_user) {
                    getFromUser(v);
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

This is the fragment layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#878787" >

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="dfgdfgdf"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/user_name"/>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/get_from_user"
        android:text="Gönder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/message_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
</LinearLayout>
```

And there is the logcat:http://prntscr.com/4a5svo

How can I fix it ? What do you suggest ?

Comment: Did you really just screenshot an error log? @_@ Regardless, it's a pretty obvious problem -- you never assign a value to your ListView variable.

Comment: Look for java.lang.NullPointerException of line 33.

Comment: Oh,this is my fault,I am sorry and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lv value is not set. add code of findviewbyid on lv you should be good

Answer (score 1):

initialize your Listview lv like you did for Textview and make sure your `strArr` Not empty

```
TextView username=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
```